# How to convert nested json data into a comma separated list with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, nested

```
var data=  [
      {
        name: "productname",
        id: "1356",
        price: "0.00",
        category: "Health",
        position: "1",
        list: "New Products",
        stocklevel: "20",
        brand: "Health"
      },
      {
        name: "productname2",
        id: "5263",
        price: "0",
        category: "Hair",
        position: "2",
        list: "New Products",
        stocklevel: "",
        brand: "Hair"
      },
      {
        name: "productname3",
        id: "7473",
        price: "0.00",
        category: "skin",
        position: "3",
        list: "New Products",
        stocklevel: "10",
        brand: "skin"
      },
      
      
     ]
```

i have data of multiple product as in nested order the product could be upto n.

but i want this data into commma seprated values As list so i can make it anylaytical friendly.

Like this

```
Product1: "productname",
Product1Price: 0.00,
Product1id: "1356",
Product1brand: "health", 
Product1stocklevel: "20",
Product2: "productname2",
Product2price: 0,
Product2id: "5263",
Product2brand: "hair",
Product2stocklevel: "",
Product3: "productname3",
Product3price: 0.00,
Product3id: "7473",
```

The product details should be show out of the nexted loop

We can separate key and values with map function. But as all product data is in same format so i am confused about how map function would work here.

Comment: Did you try [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)?  `data.map(e => \`${e.name},${e.id},${e.price}\`).join("\n")`

Comment: I have changed the question. Please check it out and mention some idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `.map` along with details from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18202926/2181514) to iterate each property:

```js
var data = [{
    name: "productname",
    id: "1234",
    price: "0.00",
    category: "Health",
    position: "1",
    list: "New Products",
    stocklevel: "20",
    brand: "Health"
  },
  {
    name: "productname2",
    id: "2345",
    price: "0",
    category: "Hair",
    position: "2",
    list: "New Products",
    stocklevel: "",
    brand: "Hair"
  },
  {
    name: "productname3",
    id: "356anything",
    price: "0.00",
    category: "skin",
    position: "3",
    list: "New Products",
    stocklevel: "10",
    brand: "skin"
  },
]
console.log(
  data.map((e, i) => {
    return Object.keys(e).map(p => `Product${i+1}${p=="name"?"":p}:"${e[p]}"`).join(",\n")
  }).join(",\n")
);
```

Added `\n` to match the expected output, unclear if you want them on a single line (comma separated list) or different lines as in your sample.

If you *don't* want the number values in quotes, then you'll have check if they're numbers first etc as your original has them in quotes.

Alternatively, and if you want them in a specific order / different case (one of your examples has Product1Price instead of Product1price) then you'll have to hardcode the output, as in the other answer.

Comment: hey thanks for answer. But can you please make it as product1price , product1id , product1name , product2name , product2id , product2price. As like without key.

Comment: Output matches your provided output sample.   Unclear what you mean by "*as like without key*".

Comment: Thanks for your valueble reply @freedomn-m.  I have updated the question. Now you can check that the id has been changed. Now what i want is output data should be in format like product1name: "productname" , product1id: "1356" , product1price: "0.00"....... product2name: "productname2" , product2id: "5263" , product2price: "0.00"........ Something like this

Comment: Ok, so you want an index rather than the data's id - updated.

Answer (score 0):

The data format you are asking is not analytic friendly!

```js
var data = [
  {
    name: "productname",
    id: "1",
    price: "0.00",
    category: "Health",
    position: "1",
    list: "New Products",
    stocklevel: "20",
    brand: "Health"
  },
  {
    name: "productname2",
    id: "2",
    price: "0",
    category: "Hair",
    position: "2",
    list: "New Products",
    stocklevel: "",
    brand: "Hair"
  },
  {
    name: "productname3",
    id: "3",
    price: "0.00",
    category: "skin",
    position: "3",
    list: "New Products",
    stocklevel: "10",
    brand: "skin"
  },
]

var result = {}

data.forEach(function(e) {
  var key = "Product" + e.id
  result[key] = e.name
  result[key + "Price"] = e.price
  result[key + "Category"] = e.category
  result[key + "Position"] = e.position
  result[key + "List"] = e.list
  result[key + "Stocklevel"] = e.stocklevel
  result[key + "Brand"] = e.brand
})

console.log('result: ', result)
```

```js
var data = {
  1356: {
    name: "productname",
    id: "1356",
    price: "0.00",
    category: "Health",
    position: "1",
    list: "New Products",
    stocklevel: "20",
    brand: "Health"
  },
  5263: {
    name: "productname2",
    id: "5263",
    price: "0",
    category: "Hair",
    position: "2",
    list: "New Products",
    stocklevel: "",
    brand: "Hair"
  },
  7473: {
    name: "productname3",
    id: "7473",
    price: "0.00",
    category: "skin",
    position: "3",
    list: "New Products",
    stocklevel: "10",
    brand: "skin"
  }
}

// Access to any product in the data set
console.log('product 5263: ', data[5263])

// And also access to any product property directly from the dataset
console.log('product name 5263: ', data[5263].name)

// Looping through the array of goods and selecting the required fields
Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
  var product = data[key]
  // Output only name and price:
  console.log(product.name, ' ', product.price)
})
```

Comment: Sorry , i have updated the question. So please check it out and if you have any idea about how can i solve it pls mention

Comment: At this point, I still don't understand the problem itself. Perhaps my translator from English doesn't help me much. I can guess, maybe you want to be able to access products by their ID like: data["1"] or data["3"] ?

Comment: javascript has arrays and hashes, iterating over arrays and hashes is slightly different: [1,2,3].forEach(function(element, index, array) { element ... }) and hash: for(var key in data) { data[key] ... })

Comment: Oo sorry !.....check now please

Comment: `Product1: "productname", Product1Price: 0.00` --- it is not array, and it is not hash =) ! Hash: `{"key_as_string": "Value"}` Array: `["String", 100]`

Comment: Can you provide actual code?.

Comment: Scroll through the code please

Comment: Hey thanks for answer but instead of key can we have static number? Like product1id , product1name , product1price , product2id , product2price.

Comment: It is difficult for me to understand your request and intentions. I've often come across a choice of how to store the data so that it's easy to get to it and loop over it. Here is a second example of how I would store the data, and how to access it. With explanations in the code. I recommend that you familiarize yourself with the basic javascript methods on your own.